# Not entering while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, mergesort, insertion-sort

[EDIT] - Nevermind, this is a really dumb question

I'm currently trying to create a program that will basically tell me when insertion sort takes a longer time than merge sort for given `a`, `b` and `n` (in this case, successive powers of 2). This is what I have so far:

```
int comparisonSort()
{

//prompt user for values of a and b 
int a = 0;
int b = 0; 
cout << "Enter the value for a" << endl; 
cin >> a; 
cout << "Enter a value for b" << endl;
cin >> b;

double insertionSortTime = 0;
double mergeSortTime = 0;
double n = 2; 

cout << outside while loop" << endl;              //check

while (insertionSortTime < mergeSortTime)
{
    cout << "inside while loop" << endl;          //check

    //compute the insertion and merge sort execution times 
    insertionSortTime = a*n*n;
    mergeSortTime = b*n*log2(n);

    cout << "is = " << insertionSortTime << " ms = " << mergeSortTime << endl;

    n = pow(n, 2);  // n^2 
}

cout << "value of n that insertion sort beat merge sort is: " << n << endl;
return 0;
}
```

when I run this, I get:

```
Enter the value for a
8
Enter a value for b
64
outside while loop
value of n that insertion sort beat merge sort is: 2
```

I have no idea why the while loop isn't getting executed... Sorry if this seems like a really simple question, but I'm new to C++ and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional in

```
while (insertionSortTime < mergeSortTime)
```

is `false` in the first iteration when both `insertionSortTime` and `mergeSortTime` are set to zero. That explains why the loop never got executed.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
while (insertionSortTime <= mergeSortTime)
```

Comment: I just realized that ten seconds ago thanks! I would accept your answer but I have to wait another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Its because you have `insertionSortTime = 0` and `mergeSortTime = 0` and the condition for your loop is `insertionSortTime < mergeSortTime`.

Of course `0` is not `< 0` so it never enters the loop.

Change it to `<=`.